# Using tar option to extract the contents of a rar file

Tags: linux

I have uploaded a rar file under linux server .
When i used `unrar -e filename.rar` or `rar -e filename.rar` , i got this error Command not found rar.
As i am not a root user , i dont have permissions to install unrar Into linux machiene .

So please tell me is it possible to use tar option to extract the contents of a rar file ??

When i used unrar under Linux machiene i got this

```
-bash-3.00$ unrar
-bash: unrar: command not found
-bash-3.00$
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the unrar or unrar-free packets from a repository.

Comment: I am not a root user , so i cant download them . :(